# Operations in Masked Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two masked numpy arrays. These are images.

I am trying to subtract one from another.

If I do the standard subtraction operator,

```
ma1 - ma2
```

It will subtract them as if they were not masked (their masks are not considered). I would like them to subtract with their masks.

Does anyone know how to subtract masked numpy arrays from eachother?

Comment: You'd better show some sample inputs and outputs ;)

Comment: What do you expect for entries that are only masked in one of the arrays? I think this is ambiguous and you should rather set the mask after the operation to make explicit what mask should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work. When you operate on masked arrays, it takes the union of the masks involved in the operation. The case below shows how `numpy` chooses the values that will be changed when you do a subtraction between two masked arrays:

```
a1 = np.random.random((100,100))
a2 = np.random.random((100,100))

a1 = np.ma.array(a1, mask=a1<0.5)
a2 = np.ma.array(a2, mask=a2<0.5)

umask = np.logical_or(a1.mask, a2.mask) # <-- union of the masks

test = a1.data - a2.data
test[umask] = a1.data[umask] # <-- "canceling" the operation according to the
                             #     combined mask

np.allclose((a1-a2), test)
#True
```

As you see, the result is the same...

Comment: Are you sure this works? I am trying it yet, getting the same problem

Comment: Both of the masks are in the same area by the way

Comment: @Highschooler do you have any input sample of your array? Perhaps you could edit your question adding this information...